# Resources or textbooks about teaching statistics (pedagogy)

Tags: references, teaching

I want to become a better teacher and, therefore, I am looking for resources or textbooks about how to teach statistics and quantitative methods to students or learners (focusing on hints on how to facilitate learning and active participation, less on the content itself).

I know [Teaching Statistics](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/bag-of-tricks/) by Andrew Gelman and Deborah Nolan but I am interested in further resources, especially focusing more on pedagogy and less on individual statistical topics such as histograms.

Interesting for me would be, for example,

- what constitutes good statistical teaching
- getting constructive feedback and evaluation
- how to address both high-performing students and those who need more time within one class
- utilization of new technologies (such as R-Shiny visualizations)
- how to teach the value and the relevance of statistical concepts (especially theory)
- communication / presentation skills (e.g. deliberate use of breaks)
- teaching concepts such as *[Flipped classroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipped_classroom)*

Any recommendations?

I would also be interested in relevant survey or review articles from journals such as *Journal of Statistics Education*, or in accessible studies which synthesize the state-of-the-art of this field of research.

Comment: Some related threads [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references+teaching).

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question for which I hope you receive a lot of answers.  Restricting attention to only statistical philosophy and intuition, the best resources currently available in my opinion are those created by Richard McElreath - his book *Statistical Rethinking* and his many freely available YouTube videos.  These represent the most intuitive introduction to statistics I've ever seen, and are able to accomplish that by not using any frequentist ideas.  By using Bayesian thinking for a student's first exposure to statistics, McElreath is able to build a logical structure whose payoff is seen by his elegant handling of measurement error, missing data, and the probability that one model is better than another in a **first statistics course**.

As a side note, I've come to believe that only by teaching Bayesian statistics first can students really understand frequentist p-values and confidence intervals.

McElreath also embraces and develops free computational and graphics tools that will help students.